# Set of N nearest neighbors in set form

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Let $X=\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and let $x\in X$. I want to describe the set of $N$ nearest neighbors in $X$, which I will denote $NN(x,N)$. For example, one formulation of the set could be

$NN(x,N)=\{y\in X | $$y$ is one of the first $N$ points minimizing $\|x-y\|_2  $}$.

However, the above formulation is far from elegant. I was hoping someone might have a better formulation. Thank you!

Comment: It isn't well defined, to begin with. What if there are 10 points at the same distance from x, and you want just 5?

Comment: (1) if you want to call the set operator "$NN$", I suggest you call the count variable something other than "$N$". (2) You could try $$NN(x,k) = \{y \in X : |\{z \in X : \|z - x\| < \|y - z\|\}| < k\}$$ where $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of a set $A$. This handles Ivan Neretin's issue by accepting all points at the maximum distance, even though that may exceed a total of $k$. If this is a problem, then you will need to add some additional consideration for distinguishing which points at this distance are to be included and which are to be discarded.